# How can you play an audio file in React without the use of a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to create one of those Pomodoro 25 + 5 timers.

I need to set an audio file to start playing once the clock reaches zero, but despite trying many tips online, I can't figure how to play the audio.

I have an `<audio></audio>` tag at the end of the file with the source link, but I don't know how to have it start once the clock reaches zero. I've managed to do it by passing it to 'onClick' attributes on buttons (not the point of the exercise), but dynamically playing it I could not figure out.

Here's the component that renders the timer (disregard the Frankenstein's monster that is startCountdown):

````
class Clock extends Component {
    state = {
        minutes: 25, 
        seconds: 0,
        breakLength: 5,
        sessionLength: 25,
        isOn: false,
        count: 1,
        type: true
    }
  startCountdown = () => {
    this.buzzer();
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
    })
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState({
        count: this.state.seconds === 1? this.state.count + 1 : null,
        seconds: this.state.seconds === 0 && this.state.minutes === 0? 0 : this.state.seconds === 0 && this.state.minutes > 0? 59 : this.state.seconds - 1,
        minutes: this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.seconds === 0 && !this.state.type
            ? this.state.breakLength
            : this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.seconds === 0 && this.state.type
                ? this.state.sessionLength
                : this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.seconds > 0
                ? 0 
                : this.state.minutes - this.state.count,
        type: this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.seconds === 1? !this.state.type : this.state.type
    }), 1000);
  }
  stopCountdown = () => {
      this.setState({
          isOn: false,
      })
      clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  resetCountdown = () => {
      this.setState({
        minutes: 25, 
        seconds: 0,
        breakLength: 5,
        sessionLength: 25,
        isOn: false,
        count: 1,
        type: true
      })
      clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  buzzer = () => {
    this.audioBeep = new Audio(this.props.src);
    if (this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.seconds === 1)
    this.audioBeep.play();
  }
breakArrowUp = () => {
    this.setState({
      breakLength: this.state.breakLength < 60? this.state.breakLength + 1 : this.state.breakLength
    })
}
breakArrowDown = () => {
  this.setState({
    breakLength: this.state.breakLength > 1? this.state.breakLength - 1 : 1
  })
}
sessionArrowDown = () => {
  this.setState({
      sessionLength: this.state.isOn? this.state.sessionLength : this.state.sessionLength > 1? this.state.sessionLength - 1: this.state.sessionLength,
      minutes: this.state.isOn? this.state.minutes : this.state.sessionLength > 1? this.state.sessionLength - 1 : 1,
      seconds: this.state.isOn? this.state.seconds : 0,
      count: 1
  })
}
sessionArrowUp = () => {
  this.setState({
      sessionLength: this.state.isOn? this.state.sessionLength : this.state.sessionLength < 60? this.state.sessionLength + 1: this.state.sessionLength,
      minutes: this.state.isOn? this.state.minutes : this.state.sessionLength < 60? this.state.sessionLength + 1: this.state.sessionLength,
      seconds: this.state.isOn? this.state.seconds : 0,
      count: 1
  })
}
    render() {
        const {breakLength, sessionLength, minutes, seconds} = this.state; 
        let fontColor = this.state.minutes >= 1? "black" : "red";
        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container-fluid p-0 text-center w-100">
                    <h1 className="text-center p-2">25 + 5 Clock</h1>
                    <div className="container text-center w-50">
                    <div className="row">
                        <h3 id="break-label" className="col text-center p-2">Break Length</h3>
                        <h3 id="session-label" className="col text-center p-2">Session Length</h3>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container text-center w-50">
                        <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <button id="break-decrement" className="btn" onClick={this.breakArrowDown}><i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
                            <span id="break-length" className="m-2">{breakLength}</span>
                            <button id="break-increment" className="btn" onClick={this.breakArrowUp}><i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col">
                            <button id="session-decrement" className="btn" onClick={this.sessionArrowDown}><i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></button>
                            <span id="session-length" className="m-2">{sessionLength}</span>
                            <button id="session-increment" className="btn" onClick={this.sessionArrowUp}><i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container text-center border rounded w-25 p-2" style={{color: fontColor}}>
                    <h4 id="timer-label">{this.state.type? "Session" : "Break"}</h4>
                        <span id="time-left">{`${minutes >= 10? minutes : "0" + minutes}:${seconds >= 10? seconds : "0" + seconds}`}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container text-center w-25 p-2">
                        <button id="start_stop" className="btn" onClick={this.playStop()}><i className="fas fa-play"></i><i className="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
                        <button id="reset" className="btn" onClick={this.resetCountdown}><i className="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <audio id="beep" preload="auto"
        src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/audio/BeepSound.wav"></audio> 
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
         );
    }
    playStop() {
        let func = this.state.isOn? this.stopCountdown : this.startCountdown;
        return func     
    }
}
 
export default Clock;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using following html tag:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**Ref:** https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Alternatively you can use npm module [howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler)

**NOTE:** Make sure you go through browser Autoplay Policies here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. Controls wouldn't work in this case because I could not render the controls to be visible , but I read a bit the links you sent me and it helped me figure out a viable solution.

Comment: @CaMo, I am glad that helped you, Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

try to check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp).

basically you can pass `autoplay` props to true to your `<audio>` tag in your given conditions.

you can say something like this:

```
<audio
   autoplay={this.state.minutes === 0 && this.state.seconds === 0}
></audio>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. I couldn't get it to work with autoplay set in that way, but your link was very useful and gave me an insight that ended up working.

Comment: how did you do it? can you put it somewhere in your question or make an answer on that?